# Dont want to use plain text password in yum.conf

Tags: proxy, yum, rhel

So when it comes to hiding behind proxies in **RHEL** machines, there are a lot of proxy authentication errors I face. Even though I have used cntlm *(cntlm.conf)* to use proxies, using YUM to install any package considers */etc/yum.conf*. The problem here is, that I have to use my **plain text password**, which I want to avoid. Is there any option so that I can encrypt the *proxy_pass* that I am providing in */etc/yum.conf* ??

Sample yum.conf file:

```
proxy=http://myproxy
proxy_username=myusername
proxy_password=my-plain-text-password
```

In the above file, I want a encrypted password instead of plain text.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any "encryption" you put in that file would, by necessity, need to be trivially reversible.

So it would be obfuscation and not "encryption" that you were doing and I don't believe yum supports anything like that.

That being said I don't think you should need a username and password in `yum.conf` if you are using `cntlm` to handle the auth for you. (Unless there's another proxy behind the ntlm proxy that also needs auth or something.)

Comment: It doesn't work out that way, even though i have added username/pass in cntlm.conf, YUM still refers yum.conf.

Comment: @vikramiyer Yes, yum will use yum.conf (it doesn't know anything about cntlm) but if the proxy doesn't need auth then yum doesn't have to care about the auth since cntlm takes care of that transparently. What failure are you getting when you don't put the creds in yum.conf and do have them in cntlm.conf?

Comment: 407 proxy authentication error. (since proxy authentication is required)

Comment: @vikramiyer You need to authenticate to cntlm? Or to the proxy that cntlm is configured to use? Have you tested that cntlm is working on its own, that is without yum?

Comment: i want to use the below command, 
cmd: yum install "pkg-name"
and i want cntlm to use the repository that i have mentioned under /etc/yum.repos.d and download the pkg.

Comment: cntlm doesn't use repositories and yum doesn't do NTLM auth. You need to set yum up to use cntlm as your proxy (with no auth) then configure cntlm to use your **real** proxy (with NTLM auth) and if you get that all working yum should Just Work. Have you gotten cntlm working to handle your NTLM auth?

Comment: yes cntlm's working fine. Now as you have mentioned, i need to figure out using yum without AUTH.

Comment: Just don't put auth entries in the yum.conf. Just point the yum.conf proxy setting at the cntlm proxy. If cntlm is working that should be all you need to do I would think.